# Can I convert a custom typescript component to a HTMLElement in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

If I have a custom component in Angular. Ex. 'my-component'

Is there a way to convert this component to a HTMLElement to pass to a function, if the function takes a HTMLElement as a parameter?

I know the HTMLElement comes from this library:
lib.dom.d.ts -> located in node_modules -> typescript -> lib -> lib.dom.d.ts -> HTMLElement

Here is an image of the element:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Angular Component class doesn't represent an actual element in the DOM, it's nothing more than a blueprint. In order to create the actual element, you first need to to create it as part of the Angular Component tree and then get a reference to the actual element in the dom through the `ElementRef`.

Of course this is only possible if everything is running in the Angular Context. The only way to use an Angular Component without Angular is to convert it into a [Custom Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), here's a pretty neat tutorial on how to do it https://medium.com/@lavanya.kakimallaiah/creating-a-custom-element-in-angular-aa2a794fd041

Comment: Hi Nam thanks for the help. Question - what do you mean by "The only way to use an Angular Component without Angular is to convert it into a Custom Element"? I'm using Angular, my project is an Angular project and my custom component has it's view that I can use as an element, ex. <my-component></my-component>

Comment: Hi, so when I said without Angular, I mean if you have like a React, Vuejs, ... or even just plain javascript, by generating a `Custom Element` from an Angular Component, you can create that component anywhere with using nothing more than just plain javascript with `document.createElement('my-angular-compoent')`. But since you're inside an Angular app, what you can do is to use `ViewChild` to get the `ElementRef` and then the `nativeElement` will give you the actual `HTMLElement` that you're looking for.

Comment: For example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lqfkzh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. I hope this is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you inject in constructor ElementRef, you can "reach" in elementRef.nativeElement

```
htmlRef:any
constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef)
{
    this.htmlRef=elementRef.nativeElement
}
```

But the really important question is: What is the reason to need the htmlRef in Angular?

Comment: Good question If you look at https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-virtual-appendSlide this method takes a slide as the parameter. Here is the .ts file header: appendSlide(slide: HTMLElement | string | HTMLElement[] | string[]) I can construct a HTML string from a custom component I've created to pass in, but would like to know if an HTMLElement would be easier and how to do it?

Comment: "the argument" slide can be the htmlRef variable (is the HTMLElement)

Comment: huh! I'm not sure what you mean? do you mean that the elementRef.nativeElement is an HTMLElement?

Comment: Yes, when we inject in constructor ElementRef, the "ElementRef.nativeElement" is the HTMLElement